# Removal or Update of .NET on Win2003 Server

Tags: .net, windows, asp-classic, windows-update

G'day,

A two pronged question for you all...

Here at work, we've prematurely put .NET 3.5 on our production server (Win 2003, which previously it had no .NET at all). Ever since, every time we apply windows updates have been restarting IIS. (Which is fair enough, since it's been patching the .NET installation.)

Now, *first question*: Is this new behaviour going to continue, or shall we assume that once it's "up to date" it'll return to the previous behaviour of rarely needing to restart?

*Second question*: What are the chances that we'll stuff something if we uninstall .NET entirely from our server?

(Info: We have been running ASP classic + a few 3rd party products from Persists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question but it's not a programmer question.

If I may offer brief and completely warrantee and guarantee free support though!:

1) There's no way to be sure of this; Installing it would have put the latest version on, it may be adding important security fixes.
If this is a worry then make time to schedule for update deployments.

2) If you've not been using it then its likely that it won't hurt to remove it; However thats not to say that something installed since then doesn't use .Net, even if your stuff doesn't.

One possible thing to check is look at the Event logs and see if there is anything for .Net at all, that would give you a hint as to what code is using .Net

Comment: Mmmm, Logs. Good thought. 
I can't see that anything new & using .NET would have been installed.

I've passed this information up the line, and have suggested better implementation of (1) rather than removal.

We'll see how we go. Once we resolve this internally, I'll update this again.

Comment: Hi Russ.

Well, this seems to now be moot, as the chief is happy to leave it on there now, as procedures have been adjusted & it doesn't seem to be having an effect anymore.

Thanks for the help :)